# Change node field with a comment

Tags: entities

I'm creating an issue tracking system with Drupal 7.

I have a content type called "Issue". in it there is a field "Assign To" that is a user reference field.

When a client create the issue he can specify the user that should handle it.

But when a client ads a comment to an issue, he sometimes want to change the assigned user.
Currently the only way to do it is by adding the comment, saving and the editing the issue, changing the "Assign To" field and saving.

I would like to make the "Assign To" (and the "Status") field available in the comment or as a separate component in the page.

Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following module that does a great job: [Comment Node Edit](http://drupal.org/sandbox/jrowny/1281972).

> Gives Site Administrators ability to mark field instances as "editable
>   by comment." When a field is editable by comment, the field will show
>   up in the "add comment" form.

Answer (score 0):

On Drupal 7, use this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_alter

That's exactly what you need in this situation.